# ObservableCollection slicing using lambda

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, lambda, observablecollection

I have `ObservableCollection<ViewUnit> _myItems` field, where `ViewUnit` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

`ViewUnit` has `Handled : bool` property.

The main view of WPF application has a `ListBox` which binds to `_myItems`.

I want a separate view of non-handled items only, that is, to have an `IObservableCollection<>` depended on existing `_myItems` but having only filtered items, preferably, using a lambda expression.

Ideally, this would be

```
IObservableCollection<ViewUnit> _myFilteredCollection = HelperClass<ViewUnit>.FromExisting(_myItems, (e) => !e.Handled);
```

I could implement it on my own. I just feel somebody though this problem through and has a good solution available (I just don't know its name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).  This is a view around a collection that handles filtering, grouping, and sorting.  When you ask WPF to bind to a collection it actually binds to its default view, so you can just filter the default collection view like this:

```
var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_myItems);
collectionView.Filter = e => !((ViewUnit)e).Handled;
```

The filter is a predicate on `object`, so you'll have to cast the parameter to `ViewUnit`.  It also won't be notified if the property changes, so you'll need to call `collectionView.Refresh` if the `Handled` property changes.  It will be updated if you add or remove from `_myItems`, though.

Also check out Bea Stollnitz's blog entry [How do I filter items from a collection](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31).

Comment: It's important to note that a CollectionView created from an ObservableCollection raises events properly.  That's a really significant strength.